# how to load a list with providers flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to how to load saved list data on new dart file with provider.

The below code is my list with provider.

'items' list will be added with integer items.

class ListProvider is in provider.dart file.

and

Swapping function is in different dart file.

How can Swapping use added data in 'items' list??

```
class ListProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  List<int> items = [
    -1,
  ];

  void addItem(int item) {
    items.add(item);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  bool contains(int item) {
    bool answer = items.contains(item);
    return answer;
  }
}

IconButton(
                  onPressed: Swapping,
                  icon: Image.asset('assets/refresh.png'),
                  iconSize: 20,
                ),


Swapping() {
    Random random = new Random();
    var numberHats = random.nextInt(items.length);
    setState(() {
      hat = hat_items[items[numberHats]];
    });
  }
```

Comment: You can use Provider.of<providerName> to get the values you will have to put that in the list builder if you want to check for changing data, Else you can directly put it in the init() call and set listen to false.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `provider`, you not should use `setState`. You need to use the `ChangeNotifierProvider` Widget:

```
     ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (context) => ListProvider(),
          child: Scaffold(
child:....
child:IconButton(
                  onPressed: Swapping,
                  icon: Image.asset('assets/refresh.png'),
                  iconSize: 20,
                ),
),
        ),
```

And then edit your model with the keyword to extend the model:

```
class ListProvider extends ChangeNotifier
```

For more details, [see the documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple).

Comment: Could you [edit] your answer to clean up the indentation in the code block? As is, it's difficult to follow.